# How to search from a certain point in a document down and end the search?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have the following code that searches for a certain point in a document and creates a search range until the end of the document. Then within that range it removes the paragraph following entirely bold paragraphs (subheadings), ignoring any styles that aren't Normal and aren't in a table. However, it seems to search the entire document (i.e. the beginning as well). How can I make it only search the range (i.e. from where I've positioned the cursor down to the end of the document)?

```
Dim aPara As Paragraph
Dim oSearchRange As Range

With Selection.Find
    .Text = "Dear "
End With
Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdParagraph, Count:=4

Set oSearchRange = Selection.Range
oSearchRange.End = ActiveDocument.Content.End

oSearchRange.MoveEnd wdParagraph, -1

For Each aPara In oSearchRange.Paragraphs
    If aPara.Range.Font.Bold = True And aPara.Range.Next.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Normal") And Not aPara.Range.Next.Information(wdWithInTable) Then aPara.Range.Next.Delete
Next aPara
```

Thanks

Comment: Probably You need `.Execute` after `.Text = "Dear "`

Comment: That did it! I can't believe (and yet I can believe it) it was something so simple, thank you :)

Comment: I'm glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add .Execute after the "Dear " search, thanks to [Teamothy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11636588/teamothy) (: